# A better / more efficient way to write this query

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count the number of records in a table.
The table is called affiliations and only has 4 columns (2 of which are foreign keys)

I want to count the number of records where the affiliated column is 0 and the business_id is related to a particular account_email.

I know how to do this query using the IN keyword, but I was wondering if there is a better or more efficient way to do this.

This is the IN version of the query:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM affiliations 
WHERE business_id IN (
    SELECT business_id 
    FROM affiliations 
    WHERE account_email = 'address@domain.ext'
) AND affiliated = 0
```

I understand I could probably replace this with EXISTS:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM affiliations 
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM affiliations 
    WHERE account_email = 'address@domain.ext'
) AND affiliated = 0
```

Would the statement with EXISTS work? And as previously asked, is there just a better way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some additional information:

business_id is not unique in this table. There is a many to many relationship between accounts and businesses in the database, and this table contains the account_emails and business_ids that are related. I am choosing an account_email, and want to get all the business_ids that account is related to, and then count the number of accounts that are also related to each of those businesses

Comment: Please post the EXPLAIN ANALYZE output of this query

Comment: how about counting business_id for account_email = 'address@domain.ext' and affiliated = 0

Comment: That would only give me the number of businesses that 'address@domain.ext' was related to where affiliated is 0. I want to get the number of accounts that are related to the same businesses as 'address@domain.ext' where affiliated is 0

Comment: @Ben Guest: so, any chance to see the `EXPLAIN` as per request?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, phpMyAdmin returns a table and I'm not too sure how to display the information here as a copy and paste just prints the table as a pretty unreadable list

Comment: @Ben Guest: use mysql console instead of PMA then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first query from the question with `IN` clause is not equivalent to the second with `EXIST`.
To convert the first query with `IN`, you must use a dependent subquery:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM affiliations a1
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM affiliations a2
    WHERE account_email = 'address@domain.ext'
      AND a1.business_id = a2.business_id
) AND affiliated = 0
```

Pay attention to this condition: `AND a1.business_id = a2.business_id`

The above query is semantically eqivalent to your first query with `IN`.
Their performance are the same as well, because MySql, during the optimalization phase, converts intenrally a condition of this form:
`outer_expr IN (SELECT inner_expr FROM ... WHERE subquery_where)`

into this:

`EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... WHERE subquery_where AND outer_expr=inner_expr)`

See this link for detalis: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subquery-optimization-with-exists.html

Pay speciall attention to discussion about NULL values and how NULL impacts the optimizer.
In short - if `business_id` column is declared as `NOT NULL`, then MySql is able to optimize these two queries.
See final conclusion (at the bottom of the page in this link):

> To help the query optimizer better execute your queries, use these tips:
>
> - A column must be declared as NOT NULL if it really is. (This also helps other aspects of the optimizer.)
> - If you don't need to distinguish a NULL from FALSE subquery result, you can easily avoid the slow execution path. Replace a comparison that looks like this:
>
>   **outer_expr IN (SELECT inner_expr FROM ...)**
>
>   with this expression:
>
>   **(outer_expr IS NOT NULL) AND (outer_expr IN (SELECT inner_expr FROM ...))**
>
>   Then NULL IN (SELECT ...) will never be evaluated because MySQL stops evaluating AND parts as soon as the expression result is clear.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use exists, but also remember to correlate the subquery to the primary table as below.

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM affiliations a
WHERE exists (
    SELECT 1
    FROM affiliations a1
    WHERE account_email = 'address@domain.ext'
    and a1.business_id=a.business_id
) AND affiliated = 0
```

Answer (score -1):

Use JOIN instead of IN.  IN is terrible for performance if you're trying to match a lot of values

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM affiliations AS ABB2
    JOIN (SELECT business_id 
          FROM affiliations 
          WHERE account_email = 'address@domain.ext') AS ABB1
        ON ABB1.business_id = ABB2.business_id
WHERE affiliated = 0
```

Comment: @Lloyd, a JOIN in not semantically equivalent to SEMI JON (exist/in), see this demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b228c/1 pay attention to results of your query and the query from the answer. Also, a performance of IN may be poor when IN contain a huge list of values (constants), but this doesn't apply for a query with `IN ( subquery )`, MySql is able to optimize such a query, and it may be even faster that strainght jonin.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the information. I will probably just stick with the IN statement. I guess the IN keyword exists for a reason and this seems like a good case to use it with.

Comment: @kordirko I was under the assumption that business_id was unique.  If not, you can add a GROUP BY in the sub-query and you'll achieve the same results.  I know a few edge cases where IN might be marginally faster than a straight JOIN, but in the vast majority of scenarios, JOIN is the same if not faster than IN.  This is especially true in older version of MySQL or those not running InnoDB.

Comment: @BenGuest I would suggest running both queries on your set of data.  Depending on the indexes on the table and the version of MySQL you are using, you could see a sizable performance improvement with using JOIN